# Print range of lines with line numbers

Tags: sed

Answers to printing a range of lines are all over.

```
sed -n '10,20p' <file>
```

prints lines 10 to 20 of `file`. Answers to printing the line numbers matching a pattern are also all over:

```
sed -n '/pattern/=;p;' <file>
```

How do I combine the two? I want to print lines 170 to 201, and I want sed to identify the line numbers I'm printing.

Comment: This might help: `cat -n file | sed -n '10,20p'`?

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {a..z} |awk 'NR>=10 && NR<=15 && /j/ {print NR,$0}'` , this will print between line 10 and 20 and the line matching `j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using Cyrus's comment as being the simplest "almost one liner."

```
cat -n <file> | sed -n '<first wanted line>,<last wanted line>p'
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Sample file

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

Command

```
cat sample.txt | sed '2,4{=;p}'
```

Output

```
2
second
3
third
4
fourth
```

**-**

To delimit the fields and display in a single line:

```
cat sample.txt | sed '2,4{=;p}' | sed 'Ns/\n/ /g'
```

Creating following output:

```
2 second
3 third
4 fourth
```